# iOS: UITableView parallax header effect like Spotify

Tags: ios, uitableview, spotify, parallax

I recently received the latest Spotify iPhone/iPod update and thought their new UI was fantastic. I want to try to replicate their playlist parallax effect, Im struggling to grasp what it is that they have done though. I've uploaded a video to [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fE2Qye9bgjw&feature=youtu.be) displaying the effect I want to achieve. My best guess is that they're using some kind of custom table header, since it sticks to the top and some scrollview delegate to show/hide different labels. Anybody out there who can figure this one out?

I've found things like [this](http://rowboatrevolution.com/2012/02/uitableview-parallax-background-a-la-path/) where they have a UIImageView behind the tableview but that doesn't really replicate the header-like behavior where a bit of the image sticks to the top. Also, having the controls for 'back' and 'options' would be a hazzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout`](https://github.com/jamztang/CSStickyHeaderFlowLayout/), but it's for CollectionView headers.

Comment: Fantastic, looks like what I need. Giving it a try! Thank you.